# Why can static solutions be found only in problems with Dirichlet boundary conditions in non-relativistic point particle mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, boundary-conditions, differential-equations, stability

Qmechanic in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/571913) answer says that *only* Dirichlet b.c.s are consistent with static solutions of point particle mechanics. Why is this so?

E.g. The standard classical harmonic oscillator problem with b.c. $x(t_i)=0,\dot{x}(t_i)=0$ is not a Dirichlet b.c. but still returns the static solution $x(t)=0$. What is my mistake here?