# Is action ever stationary in quantum theory, or is it always minimal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

The question says it all.

Is there an example from quantum theory of quantum field theory where action is only stationary, but not minimal?

(There are such examples in classical physics - but do they exist in quantum physics?)

Comment: What would prohibit you from taking the classical examples you already know and quantizing them?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122486/2451 and links therein.