Global sign of Dirac action
Why has David Tong in his Standard Model Lectures a global minus sign in front of the Dirac action?
$$S_\mathrm{Dirac}=-\int\mathrm{d}^4x(\operatorname{i}\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi-M\bar{\psi}\psi)$$
This convention is also used on page 186 when he couples the fermions to the gauge fields.

Which eq. numbers? ...Ah found it: eq. (1.57).

@Qmechanic 1.57 and 5.25 for example

Looking at the mass term may help. For sign conventions, see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100557/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338927/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41603/226902

More on conventions in the Dirac equation.
